# Magento 2 login error : SSM Number" is a required value. "Username" is a required value

Tags: login, registration

Im using magento 2.2.1 , suddenly not able to create account for customer 
Showing error (SSM Number" is a required value. "Username" is a required value. "Regulation" is a required value)

Please guide on how to resolve the issue

really appreciate kind assistance

URL : https://www.mycliks.com/

Comment: check your social plugin

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer, i just disabled social login in my admin, but still the same error , kindly advice

Comment: Have you run this commands: `php bin/magento cache:flush`,  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy`?
Because that popup is still there still social action working.

Comment: its disabled now , but when i want to register as seller , its showing same error again , kindly assist on this as im struggling with it for 2 days

Comment: Have you/developer has created any customer attribute OR have you added any module for `ssm number` for Malaysia country?

Comment: developer not with us now - if it was created , how to disable it?

Comment: Are you familiar with database query?

if yes, please run this query `SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'username';` Let me know what you getting by this query.

Comment: Hi , im really not familiar with this , can guide me , i really neet to resolve the issue

Comment: Create custom PHP file on your Magento root and paste this code in that file then run it in your browser.
<?php 
`use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';$params = $_SERVER;$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');$connection = $resource->getConnection();$sql = "Select * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'username'"; $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); print_r($result)`
?>

Comment: try tat and let me know what you are getting. If that PHP file unable to access then try to put that  in `pub/static/frontend/`

Comment: can add me in skype - my first name is my id - it will b more helpful